How to load transparent images correctly using raylib
I am writing a basic flappy bird game but when I use "DrawTexture" to draw my texture it loaded the player.png texture but it loaded the checker-like pattern instead of making the background invisible so at first I thought it was a problem with my .png so i tried 3 others and they all had the same problem so then I added "Color transparent = {255,255,255,100};" and I loaded it as a color with "DrawTexture()" and so here's the current code I have:
#include<iostream>
#include "raylib.h"

int main(){
    InitWindow(608,457,"Flappy Bird");
    Texture2D background = LoadTexture("bg.png");
    Texture2D player = LoadTexture("player.png");
    Color transparent = {255,255,255,100};
    SetBlendMode(BLEND_ALPHA);
    while(!WindowShouldClose()){
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        BeginDrawing();
        DrawTexture(background,0,0,WHITE);
        DrawTexture(player,0,10,transparent);
        EndDrawing();
    }

}


Use a image editor to remove it. it has nothing to do specifically with raylib.

This is part of the raylib header:
   #define WHITE      CLITERAL(Color){ 255, 255, 255, 255 }   // White
   #define BLANK      CLITERAL(Color){ 0, 0, 0, 0 }           // Blank (Transparent)

What you are trying is white, what you should do instead is { 0, 0, 0, 0 } or BLANK.
